# Missing ShutdownManager class in C++ based UWP app?

Tags: c++, uwp, windows-iot-core-10

I'm currently playing around with Windows IoT Core and I'm trying to develop a C++ based UWP app for Raspberry Pi 3b. 
I want to reboot/shutdown the Pi from inside the app but I'm not sure how I can do this.

The UWP api reference lists the C# [Windows.System](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system) which corresponds to C++ Windows::System. But it seems that not all classes are available in C++.
The [UWP samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-iotcore-samples/tree/develop/Samples/IoTCoreDefaultApp) (C#) utilize the ShutdownManager class for reboot and shutdown but it is not existing in the C++ namespace. Now I'm not sure how I'm supposed to implement this functionality by utilizing the API. Are there any other possibilities to solve this for C++?

**Solution:**
I was missing the **Windows IoT Extensions for the UWP**. These have to manually added in Visual Studio by right clicking the Project, then Add -> Reference -> Universal Windows -> Extensions. Now I have access to the namespace and was able to reboot and shutdown my device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But it seems that not all classes are available in C++.

Did it mean when you built the C++ UWP project, it can not build successfully, or when you ran the app on device, an exception appeared?

The ShutdownManager API is available in C++, indeed it is included in Windows::System namespace, please refer to this [document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt694883.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp). And please note that:

> This API requires the use of the IoT **systemManagement** capability, and
>   the inclusion of iot in the **IgnorableNamespaces** list. Users can add
>   the following to their **Package.appmanifest**: , and add iot to their existing list of
>   IgnorableNamespaces.

Following code works fine on my device.

```
TimeSpan ts;
ts.Duration = 1000;
ShutdownManager::BeginShutdown(ShutdownKind::Shutdown, ts);
```

Comment: The app compiles fine as long as I don't use any of these extra features. But you gave me the right direction in what I was missing. One has to add corresponding references to the project explicitely. Then the Windows IoT Extensions for UWP have to be added. I will edit my post accordingly. Thank you.